# Rails 5 : Devise Oauth Referral param not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, parameters, devise

I have an app where user can register using email, facebook or google, also I have small referral system where user can share link and earn points.

Now everything works perfectly registering and login. But referral system works only when creating account using social networks.

the following is my code :

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
  # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)

  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

  if @user.persisted?
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication 
    #this will throw if @user is not activated
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
# google callback
def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Google') if is_navigational_format?
    else
        flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in through Google. Please register or try signing in later.'
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end 
end

def failure
    flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in. Please register or try signing in later.' 
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
def build_resource(hash = {})
  super

  if cookies[:referral_code] && referrer = User.find_by(referral_code: cookies[:referral_code])
    self.resource.referred_by = referrer
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
before_validation :set_referral_code
validates :referral_code, uniqueness: true
def set_referral_code
    loop do
        self.referral_code = SecureRandom.hex(6)
        break unless self.class.exists?(referral_code: referral_code)
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

before_action :set_referral_cookie
def set_referral_cookie
    if params[:ref]
      cookies[:referral_code] = {
        value: params[:ref],
        expires: 30.days.from_now,
      }
    end
end
```

I built my system using help of this repository

[gorails referral system](https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/referral-program)

### Edit

```
Started GET "/?ref=6c28f9668715" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 21:23:32 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"ref"=>"6c28f9668715"}
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 125ms (Views: 90.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 21:23:34 +0100
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["referral_code", "6c28f9668715"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:7
  Rendering users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 300ms (Views: 142.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 21:23:37 +0100
I, [2019-01-27T21:23:37.266108 #67828]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 21:23:38 +0100
I, [2019-01-27T21:23:38.488342 #67828]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAemLam_HRACk1q5NTfix5Sve6rA1fsDD5z_21vKpDlaTq4hfuXM2Oh_CThPspwk1BIg4Tjc1bm0UOcXLo_X0XGVI8XdLsirhPV6wKnGiCO3uU3l4y6y31qnhC1xjzd-21wx_cWVO-ipPCzrZ8kqWCdvQrxxKOQXMj10LsKlTAbuSqMEpx90XvcZw3RAYGLSiEFQGJSgCpABpboh_n_ewjTbfbTB01JATW6hM9Wy8iN1AQLpXrRgOZ-5P1NdowqdHdjU420N6QoB7R9tyHXegioQ47J8cjgCMUFwDPi_T--zHK6_-sIkW_QE6P5ryot1qHxzHpOASvx46WHvJun5_Yh&state=bd3dfbf7e7a5c83c42d1d754149d7be5ea7f39b6d5b99b28" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 21:23:39 +0100
I, [2019-01-27T21:23:39.483990 #67828]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQAemLam_HRACk1q5NTfix5Sve6rA1fsDD5z_21vKpDlaTq4hfuXM2Oh_CThPspwk1BIg4Tjc1bm0UOcXLo_X0XGVI8XdLsirhPV6wKnGiCO3uU3l4y6y31qnhC1xjzd-21wx_cWVO-ipPCzrZ8kqWCdvQrxxKOQXMj10LsKlTAbuSqMEpx90XvcZw3RAYGLSiEFQGJSgCpABpboh_n_ewjTbfbTB01JATW6hM9Wy8iN1AQLpXrRgOZ-5P1NdowqdHdjU420N6QoB7R9tyHXegioQ47J8cjgCMUFwDPi_T--zHK6_-sIkW_QE6P5ryot1qHxzHpOASvx46WHvJun5_Yh", "state"=>"bd3dfbf7e7a5c83c42d1d754149d7be5ea7f39b6d5b99b28"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "311741132783400"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:60
  Disk Storage (5.7ms) Uploaded file to key: Sp8DiDxRWFn3uUfGTJJHdABc (checksum: tjmoDYRADOqNyXiWy90gxg==)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:66
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (44.9ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "Sp8DiDxRWFn3uUfGTJJHdABc"], ["filename", "avatar.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 1640], ["checksum", "tjmoDYRADOqNyXiWy90gxg=="], ["created_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.423862"]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/globalize-3fe2f93ab2d0/lib/patches/active_record/persistence.rb:12
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:66
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:66
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:66
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:60
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2 AND "users"."referral_code" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "311741132783400"], ["referral_code", "2925f372e912"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:79
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "qubitam@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/globalize-3fe2f93ab2d0/lib/patches/active_record/rails5_1/uniqueness_validator.rb:38
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["referral_code", "2925f372e912"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/globalize-3fe2f93ab2d0/lib/patches/active_record/rails5_1/uniqueness_validator.rb:38
  User Create (2.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "provider", "uid", "referral_code") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "qubitam@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$JUxrDl1I4uDQwxi3yRVrnuqRJNYQJA8BcvLrmAj29nwBggJknrP3i"], ["name", "Abdelmoumin Mokhtari"], ["created_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.483417"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.483417"], ["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "311741132783400"], ["referral_code", "2925f372e912"]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/globalize-3fe2f93ab2d0/lib/patches/active_record/persistence.rb:12
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "image"], ["record_type", "User"], ["record_id", 13], ["blob_id", 10], ["created_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.487979"]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/globalize-3fe2f93ab2d0/lib/patches/active_record/persistence.rb:12
  User Update (41.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.490719"], ["id", 13]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:60
   (40.9ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:60
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fa636abf0e8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://classifyads/ActiveStorage::Blob/10>>
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:8
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35] Performing ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35) from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fa636aac790 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://classifyads/ActiveStorage::Blob/10>>
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35]   Disk Storage (0.2ms) Downloaded file from key: Sp8DiDxRWFn3uUfGTJJHdABc
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35] Skipping image analysis because the mini_magick gem isn't installed
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35]    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35]   ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35]   ActiveStorage::Blob Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "active_storage_blobs" SET "metadata" = $1 WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $2  [["metadata", "{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}"], ["id", 10]]
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35]   ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/globalize-3fe2f93ab2d0/lib/patches/active_record/persistence.rb:7
  User Update (82.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "sign_in_count" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_at" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "last_sign_in_ip" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7  [["sign_in_count", 1], ["current_sign_in_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.581519"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.581519"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-27 20:23:42.584122"], ["id", 13]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/globalize-3fe2f93ab2d0/lib/patches/active_record/persistence.rb:7
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35]    (61.8ms)  COMMIT
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35]   ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35] Performed ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 1f7ce124-dc8b-4302-912e-7b1138656e35) from Async(default) in 122.16ms
   (79.1ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:8
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/edit
Completed 302 Found in 2383ms (ActiveRecord: 297.1ms)


Started GET "/users/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 21:23:42 +0100
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/qubitam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Rendering users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 13], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb:8
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb:8
  Rendered users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (14.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (3.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 100.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

Comment: Could you attach logs which are generated after creating account?

Comment: I updated the post above with the logs